# UWP Mutliple listviews within horizontal ScrollViewer to scroll page overflow

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to display N number of ListViews on a page, but I'm struggling with the scrolling. I have got 3 ListViews on a page which overflows (intended behaviour). What I would like to happen is to be able to scroll each ListView independently on their Y axis, but I want to be able to scroll the entire group of ListViews on the X axis on the page if that makes sense.

Here's an image to try and show what I'm after:

[image]

Here's my XAML on the page:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,55">
        <Grid>
            <ListView IsHitTestVisible="{ x:Bind Vm.ListIsLoaded, Mode=OneWay }" Visibility="{ Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleList, Converter={ StaticResource IsCheckedVisibilityConverter } }" 
                      Header="ListView"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      ItemsSource="{ x:Bind Vm.List}" 
                      Margin="10,55,0,55" 
                      Width="210"
                      Padding="10">
                <!-- Listview items -->
            </ListView>

            <ListView IsHitTestVisible="{ x:Bind Vm.ListIsLoaded, Mode=OneWay }" Visibility="{ Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleList, Converter={ StaticResource IsCheckedVisibilityConverter } }" 
                      Header="ListView"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      ItemsSource="{ x:Bind Vm.List}" 
                      Margin="225,55,-75,55" 
                      Width="210"
                      Padding="10">
                <!-- Listview items -->
            </ListView>

            <ListView IsHitTestVisible="{ x:Bind Vm.ListIsLoaded, Mode=OneWay }" Visibility="{ Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleList, Converter={ StaticResource IsCheckedVisibilityConverter } }" 
                      Header="ListView"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      ItemsSource="{ x:Bind Vm.List}" 
                      Margin="440,55,-290,55" 
                      Width="210"
                      Padding="10">
                <!-- Listview items -->
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <controls:NavigationControl></controls:NavigationControl>
</Grid>
```

What's actually happening when I've been tinkering is either one of two things:

1. Neither the horizontal scroll OR each ListView will scroll at all
2. I can scroll an independent ListView vertically, but I still can't scroll the page horizontally

**Edit**
I suppose a TLDR is that I want similar scrolling behaviour as the Windows Store - but flipped 90 degrees so the main axis is horizontal.

Comment: have you considered using a Pivot control? with that you'll have clear demarcation for a horizontal scroll behavior(your tabs) and a vertical scroll behavior (your listviews). Also on a pointer device you'll only use the mouse scroll to scroll your listviews and click on tabs to switch, which will provide a better experience. If you want I can write up an answer for the same if you want the code sample

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have considered the Pivot control, but I feel like for the purpose of this app, users need to be able to freely see and possibly compare what's in each List without being restricted to one at a time.

Comment: What about a hub control then? You can simply define multiple hub sections for each listView

Comment: What would using a Hub give me over Justin XL's answer?

Comment: Under the hood, the Hub is using a ScrollViewer too... If you need extra stuff provided by the Hub, then go ahead and use it; otherwise, use the lightest control for the job.

Comment: Well because it's not the ideal way to for when you need two axis scrolling. With a hub control you'll be able to leverage the native behaviours that come in with such a two axis scroll and you can style it in a better manner making your UI even more graceful with parallax and padding properly defined sections with almost no effort when compared to the two scrollviewers

Comment: Perhaps I'll give the Hub control another chance and see if the behaviour is any better. I will be doing UI work in the future so I think I'll need to do some "fancy" UI work on both methods and see how things work. I will also be dynamically adding new ListViews with the idea that a user will search -> hits HTTP endpoint -> Gets Data -> Creates new ObservableCollection and ListView to match.

Comment: @AdityaSharma, no that's incorrect. The Hub control uses a SV for two axis scrolling behind the scenes... Also Composition parallax is built with SV too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is these two settings on your `ScrollViewer` -

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

---

Note the following scrolling related properties of a `ScrollViewer` have the following default values -

```
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = Disabled
VerticalScrollBarVisibility = Visible
HorizontalScrollMode = Auto
VerticalScrollMode = Auto
```

---

### Update

Also, I noticed you are using a `Grid` inside and it's not given enough width for the parent `ScrollViewer` to scroll horizontally. In your case, a `StackPanel` might be a better choice. Alternatively, you can use a `Grid` with three columns. Here is an example with a `StackPanel`.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,55">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListView IsHitTestVisible="{ x:Bind Vm.ListIsLoaded, Mode=OneWay }" Visibility="{ Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleList, Converter={ StaticResource IsCheckedVisibilityConverter } }" 
              Header="ListView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.List}" 
              Margin="10" 
              Width="210"
              Padding="10">
            <!-- Listview items -->
        </ListView>

        <ListView IsHitTestVisible="{ x:Bind Vm.ListIsLoaded, Mode=OneWay }" Visibility="{ Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleList, Converter={ StaticResource IsCheckedVisibilityConverter } }" 
              Header="ListView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.List}" 
              Margin="10" 
              Width="210"
              Padding="10">
            <!-- Listview items -->
        </ListView>

        <ListView IsHitTestVisible="{ x:Bind Vm.ListIsLoaded, Mode=OneWay }" Visibility="{ Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleList, Converter={ StaticResource IsCheckedVisibilityConverter } }" 
              Header="ListView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.List}" 
              Margin="10" 
              Width="210"
              Padding="10">
            <!-- Listview items -->
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I tried those settings and no dice. Here's a screenshot of the actual app: http://imgur.com/a/8GhZ7. As you can see, the scrollbar is there, but there's no tracker. If I use touch, it just bounces back (as there's nowhere to scroll)

Comment: Changing from a Grid to StackPanel has now allowed my horizontal scrolling of all items, but I've now lost the ability to scroll each ListView independently

Comment: *facepalm* I didn't take off my HorizontalAlignment on my ListView controls. I'm now able to scroll as I'd expect! Thank you!

Comment: No worries. :) You only need those two scrolling properties above. Note `Hidden` needs to be replaced by `Disabled` for `VerticalScrollBarVisibility`.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of answers suggesting a Hub control instead of the ScrollViewer, would you recommend using a Hub instead of my approach?

Comment: I wouldn't use a `Hub` control for anything. I don't like it as it doesn't offer me anything exciting (unlike the `Panorama` control back in WP7). You get the same panning from a `ScrollViewer` and it's got tons of other features like snapping. I built a `Tab` control based on it and you can take a look at a demo [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/353#issuecomment-314133650). But having said all this, the `Hub` does do what you currently have. Maybe give it a go and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Hub control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Hub) to do it. It has many features that will be useful in your case like Header, panning/scrolling etc.

Here is the syntax for Hub:

```
<Hub>
    <HubSection>
        <ListView/>
    </HubSection>

    <HubSection>
        <ListView/>
    </HubSection>

    ....

</Hub>
```

For more info: [Hub control/pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/hub), [Hub Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Hub)

Comment: I tried to use a Hub before using the ListViews and I couldn't seem to get things to work, but perhaps I quit on it too early.

Comment: for the mentioning the ideal approach for such a case scenario +1